# ROS package: 64 bit vs 32 bit.Problems in execution

Tags: 32bit-64bit, point-cloud-library, ros

I have a ROS package that uses PCL libraries  and that works perfectly in Groovy and Hydro, both in 64 bit machines.
In 32 bit machines, I can compile the package exactly the same way, without problems, but in execution it does not work.
The callbacks in it go indredibly slow, sometimes taking more than a minute, when in 64 bit they work perfectly fine.
Any possible causes for this package being stuck in 32 bit?
I am runnning Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with Hydro and Groovy, and Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit with Hydro.

Thank you all in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The execution problems were due to the processing power difference between 32 and 64 bit, and also due to RAM memory available in both systems.
Downsampling the point cloud that I was trying to process solved the problem and now the algorithm runs ok in 32 bit platform.

Thanks to all,

Alberto